# C++ Version of Python's "try: except:"

Tags: c++

In Python, there is a way of executing code under "except" if there is an error performing the code under "try".

Example:

```py
try:
    import urllib

except ImportError:
    import urllib2
```

I am quite new to C++, and I'm trying to clear the console, but the way to do it is different on Mac (`system("clear")`) and Windows (`system("cls")`)

If I were to try that on Python, it would resemble:

```py
try: 
    system("clear") 
except Error:
    system("cls")
```

I have tried `try{ }  catch{ }` but from what I've seen it's not used to work around errors.

What is the best way to do that in C++?

Comment: `system` does not throw exceptions. It uses return values to indicate status codes, but it is implementation defined what exactly is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem you could use macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __linux__
#define SO "Linux"
#elif _WIN32
#define SO "Windows"
#elif _APPLE_
#define SO "Mac"
#endif
```

I'm not quite sure about the macro for mac try *APPLE* , *OSX*
More info in: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002850-SW13